# What is the difference between & and && in octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, boolean-logic, bitwise-and

Initially I had used a single `&`. However, Octave said to use a "MATLAB style short cut". So I changed to double `&&`. As you can see, the equality finder works with single `&` but not with `&&`:

```
find(node(:,1)==b && node(:,2)==ro)
  ans = [](0x0)
find(node(:,1)==b & node(:,2)==ro)
  ans =  6
```

Why aren't the two results equal?

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question enlarge the code to a [mcve], i.e. code that **we** can run. In case your variables are proprietary and/or very large, please use `randi()` or similar to reproduce the mentioned behaviour. It's difficult for us to say what's going on, as we don't have your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double logical operations, `&&` and `||` are short-circuit operation.

They have a very powerful use: They don't evaluate all the conditions. This is very useful for things like:

`if (a==5) && super_slow_computation_here()`

In the above case, if `a` is not equal to `5`, `super_slow_computation_here` won't be even computed, it will "short circuit" the `if` condition, as we know it won't be true (`and`). With a single `&` it will compute both, then compute the `and`.

Obviously this is not what you want, you want all the conditions computed, because you are calling `find`, you need all rows of your array used. So why does Octave suggest to use double? **Because Octave is wrong**. Octave sees you using 2 arrays and a logical operator and assumes that you are using them within an `if` and not `find`, so suggests that. Ignore Octave ;)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about other part of the question ? Why & works and not &&? And Why are these people closing my question when they are not even answing. Really annoying.

Comment: @CrimeFighterCE hum what did you not understand from my asnwer, so I can explain better? I tried to explain why are they different, does that not explain why one does not work? They closed the question following Stackoverflow rules: Your post did not contain a [mcve]. I think that its good enough to pass for valid, but please do provide one in the future.

Comment: I understand shortcircuit operation. It is only to save time. And it comes to effect only incase of false results. Both should give the same output. But in this case it gives different result. I had a 10k line long list of nodes. And it was a random mesh I generated. It did work with other meshes. So was it just a mistake.

Comment: Not sure if you get, ti, trying to be more clear: `node(:,1)==b && node(:,2)==ro` will only evaluate the second index (`node(2,1)` and `node(2,2)` comparisons) if the first one is not `False`. If it is false, then it means that the total `&&` "and" operation will be false, and therefore there is no need to evaluate it. This is why you get the `ans` that you get.

Comment: Ah. Got that now. I thought it would evaluate only <node(:,1)==b>. And only if it is true it will do the node(:,2)==ro. I thought you are meaning it sideways between different conditions. Now i get that you meant evaluating each row for all conditions. So it is better to use '&' when I need to check all the conditions for all the entire array of data as in the case of 'find'. Thanks a lot.